# Only Food is Donuts

Tags: humans, health

Imagine a world where donuts were the only source of food.

How long would the average human live? How would that change Healthcare? How many species of doughnut trees would evolve?

Comment: You do realize doughnuts are an artificial food item, no part of which comes from trees, right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it's far too broad. The answer essentially boils down to: Depends on what you mean by 'food'...

Comment: You mention "donut trees." Are you implying that all plants produce some kind of donut variant? Like trees grow apple flavored donuts and potato donuts can be dug out of the ground? 

Also, what happens to animals? We eat fish. Are all the fish donuts now? How does a donut fish work?

Comment: Similarly what sort of nutrients do potato donuts and apple donuts provide?  Do fish donuts have protein in useful quantities?

Comment: Chris - that's exactly what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: Lol donut trees

Comment: Hmm... donut trees...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well obviously people's insides would evolve to live off of donuts. People would add other types of toppings to the donuts to make up for other nutrients, such as strawberries, salad, steak, chicken, and maybe even more donuts.

You would have either the near eradication or spread of diabetes due to the massive amounts of sugar. People might lose legs and rascal sales will skyrocket where you can buy them with 4wd and spinners. The food industry will be stunned and we will more than likely solve world hunger due to the whole world only growing and living off of one type of meal.

Obviously, this is a constructed world so I hope other posters don't get any donuts.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are in the process of being closed.

Comment: Well OP said my answer was useful and you've said nothing to contribute. Maybe you could had Pmed me?